# How to get children's world position in a GridLayoutGroup in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a scroll view, in its content object there's a GridLayoutGroup component(the content object has its own position and scales instead of (0,0,0) or (1,1,1) ), and under it there're several images. During runtime I want to take out an image and set its parent to other UI object, but I want the image remain its position on screen.

However I tried all the following ways, all ended up with wrong position on screen(the image moved sometimes even off screen).

1 Use SetParent method on the image object(tried both True or false as second parameter):

```
imageObject.transform.SetParent(otherObj, True);
```

2 Use SetParent method in the 1st way, then give a position to the image manually, but id does not appear at the mouse position(this code works fine for other objects that are not in a layoutgroup):

```
imageObject.transform.SetParent(otherObj, True);
var p = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
imageObject.transform.position = new Vector3(p.x, p.y, 0);
```

3 Set the position to its original value after calling SetParent.

```
var p = imageObject.transform.position;
imageObject.transform.SetParent(otherObj, True);
imageObject.transform.position = new Vector3(p.x, p.y, 0);
```

4 don't use any code but during runtime in the editor, manually drag the image out to targeted parent object. Still its position is changed.

5 don't use any code but during runtime in the editor, manually uncheck the GridLayoutGroup to disable it. Still the image position is changed.

Why the 3rd way is not working? I think probably the transform.position of the image object is not used so the value is not used so the value is not where the position is on screen, or something happened in the end of the frame so my reseting of the position is useless.

More info: my canvas render mode is set to "Screen Space-Camera". But even changed it to overlay, it remained the same result. Canvas scaler mode is "Scale with Screen Size", screen match mode is "Expand".

So what should I do to take out the image out of the GridLayoutGroup but let it stays where it is on screen? Thanks!

Comment: I think in example 3 you should store position before you set a parent.

Comment: @obywan Thanks for your reply. It's a mistake here, just edited it. I did it right in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After several tests, I found out that the position after you call `SetParent(objParent, True);` is right; but due to something related with GridLayoutGroup, the position is changed in the time after this and before the end of the frame. So take a record of that position and do whatever you need in other frames.

Example:

in main thread:

```
 imageObject.transform.SetParent(otherObj, True);
 originalPosition = imageObject.transform.position;
 imageObject.SetObjectActive(false); // If not do this, the image might flicker at it's position before put it into the GridLayoutGroup. My guess is that it gets rendered before the AdjustTransInTheEndOfFrame method is executed.
 StartCoroutine(AdjustTransInTheEndOfFrame(imageObject));

 private IEnumerator AdjustTransInTheEndOfFrame(GameObject obj) 
 {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        obj.transform.position = originalPosition;
        obj.SetObjectActive(true);
 }
```

Comment: yup WaitForEndOfFrame did it for me after breaking my head as to why I could not get the position. thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've made test project. Didn't solve your problem completely, but I got parent changing working for GridLayoutGroup located at `0,0,0` with:

1. Use `RectTransform.anchoredPosition` to get relative position in
   `GridLayoutGroup`.
2. Change parent
3. Make sure anchors of images remain the same (grid layout can change anchor of image).
4. Wait for end of frame after changing parent to set new anchor.
5. Set new `anchoredPosition` for your `RectTransform`.
6. If as you said your GridLayoutGroup has scale different from `1,1,1`
   then divide/multiply coordinates accordingly (divide by 2 for `0.5,
   0.5, 0.5`)
7. (If your Grid in not located in `(0,0,0)` you may also need to make
   some alignments)

Comment: Thanks, why wait for end of frame?

Comment: I used to just use simple ways shown in examples, and made it worked, but I didn't test for some time and too many codes and structures are changed recently in my project. Now I can't get it work again like before :(

Comment: About WaitForEndOfFrame — if you set anchor right after changing parent it will remain the same. Not sure why exactly, maybe because of execution order.

Answer (score 0):

I use this function:

```
public Vector2 GetChildLocalPosition(RectTransform rectTransformGrid, RectTransform rectTransformChild)
{
   var localPositionGrid = (Vector2)rectTransformGrid.localPosition;
   var sizeDeltaGrid = rectTransformGrid.sizeDelta;
   var deltaGridFromCenterToLeftTop = new Vector2(-0.5f * sizeDeltaGrid.x, 0.5f * sizeDeltaGrid.y);

   var anchoredPositionChild = rectTransformChild.anchoredPosition;
   var childPosition = localPositionGrid + anchoredPositionChild + deltaGridFromCenterToLeftTop;
   return childPosition;
}
```

If you need, please update the GridLayoutGroup as given below:

```
public void UpdateGrid(LayoutGroup gridLayoutGroup)
{
   gridLayoutGroup.CalculateLayoutInputHorizontal();
   gridLayoutGroup.CalculateLayoutInputVertical();
   gridLayoutGroup.SetLayoutHorizontal();
   gridLayoutGroup.SetLayoutVertical();
}
```